# wpf richtextbox: error on "decor == TextDecorations.Strikethrough"

Tags: c#, wpf

trying to detect if Selected Text in RichTextbox is underline or strikethrough..  Get a Syntax error on the function calls..  not sure how to resolve.

I have it working for the case of Bold and Italics however.  Seems like TextDecorations doesn't exists in .NET library in a similar way as Bold and Italics cases?

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<Grid>
   <RichTextBox Name="RichTextBox1"/>
</Grid>
</Window>
```

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;
namespace WpfApp1
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private bool SelectionIsStrikethrough()
        {
            var decor = RichTextBox1.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextDecorationsProperty);
            var unset = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            var SelectionIsStrike = decor != unset && (TextDecorations)decor == TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
            return SelectionIsStrike;
        }

        private bool SelectionIsUnderline()
        {
            var decor = RichTextBox1.Selection.GetPropertyValue(TextDecorationsProperty);
            var unset = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            var SelectionIsStrike = decor != unset && (TextDecorations)decor == TextDecorations.Underline;
            return SelectionIsStrike;
        }
        
        private bool SelectionIsBold()
        {
            var weight = RichTextBox1.Selection.GetPropertyValue(FontWeightProperty);
            var unset = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            var SelectionIsBold = weight != unset && (FontWeight)weight == FontWeights.Bold;
            return SelectionIsBold;
        }
        private bool SelectionIsItalic()
        {
            var style = RichTextBox1.Selection.GetPropertyValue(FontStyleProperty);
            var unset = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
            var SelectionIsItalic = style != unset && (FontStyle)style == FontStyles.Italic;
            return SelectionIsItalic;
        }
    }       
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
private bool SelectionIsUnderline()
{
var decor = mEdit.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty);
var unset = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
var SelectionIsStrike = decor != unset && decor == TextDecorations.Underline;
return SelectionIsStrike;
}

private bool SelectionIsStrikethrough()
{
var decor = mEdit.Selection.GetPropertyValue(Inline.TextDecorationsProperty);
var unset = DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
var SelectionIsStrike = decor != unset && decor == TextDecorations.Strikethrough;
return SelectionIsStrike;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).